# Missing Mime type. is that even normal?

Tags: php, html

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU3e2.jpg

So I am uploading some images but when I run it against some would be php validation This photos seems not to have a mime/type. should I measure against the text extension instead? (explode(".","img.jpg")) or is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MIME type for uploaded files is set by the client, not by the server. As such, it is completely unreliable.

If you want to check that a file actually is an image of a given format, you should rather use the exif_imagetype function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php